# Java Google App engine Hello World package error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, package

I am confused with packages in java, so please cut me some slack.

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import com.google.api.server.spi.auth.common.User; 
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.AnnotationBoolean;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api; 
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod; 
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace; 
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiResourceProperty; 
import com.google.api.server.spi.response.NotFoundException; 
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException;
```

The error I am getting is

> com.example.helloworld does not exist.

If I delete the package, it just says it cannot find the imports. I pretty sure I follow the steps properly, but in my "com" directory, there exist no folder call "google." What is the next step.

Comment: in you src directory is there a directory structure `com/example/helloworld` ?

Comment: The package structure must match the folder structure. If you place your code in package com.example.helloworld, the whatever.java file must be in a folder com/example/helloworld/whatever.java

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be good if you remove "package com.example.helloworld" from your code. It seems your code is in default package so you won't need that.